# ubuntu 12.10 on virtualbox compiz error

Tags: compiz, virtualbox

Hi I have installed ubuntu on virtual box with virtual clone drive 5.4 like the following:

but then I get the following error:
The application Compiz has closed unexpectedly

additional information:

The version of virtual box is 4.2, the host OS is windows 8, and the reason why I am using a virtual clone drive is because I don't have a cd or usb on me at the moment.

Comment: Please add the follwing information to your question (press [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/219655/edit) to do so): version of Virtual Box, host OS, Guest Additions installed? Also please state why you needed Virtual Clone Drive for installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Compiz will occasionally crash within 12.10 right now.  Most likely because 12.10 will run in software rendering mode rather than attempt to use 3D acceleration.

Check out this post to see if it helps:
[Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-an-ubuntu-12-10-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly/214968#214968)