# Improve Ubuntu 12.10 performance on VM

Tags: performance

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 on a virtual machine in Win7. It is really slow and I wanted to ask what can I do to improve it. I have set 2GB RAM(from 4GB on physical machine) and 16GB hard disk for the machine. I need to run only [Player/Stage simulator](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/) from the Ubuntu and some text editor for the source code writing.

- Can I lighten the GUI as in windows. There are a lot of animations that I don't really need
- Can you suggest some disabling of applications or services

I would appreciate every advice.

Comment: vmware/vmplayer or virtualbox needs additional tools (the virtual computer's drivers), have you installed them?

Comment: Yes, I installed vmware tools, but I can not see some improvement.

Comment: I never faces any issue with such config. :( however, you can go for lubuntu or xubuntu which are designed to be used in low powered system. Or you can install `cinemon`/`xfce`/`lxde` & get rid of `unity-desktop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this and a combination of these might even be better.

- Instead of the vanilla kernel, you might want to install a virtualization guest kernel, e.g. `linux-image-virtual`
- Instead of a 3d-accelerated desktop, you might want to try a classic one, like windowmaker or openbox.
- You might start with a text mode install and only add the minimum required packages.
- Your mileage may drop severely if you run a 64-bit guest in a 32-bit host, however running a 32-bit guest in a 64-bit host might work better than 64/64.
- You might want to try a different virtualization software VirtualBox, VirtualPC, ...
- You might check your BIOS if virtualization support is enabled at all.
- Have a look at [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) or [andlinux](http://www.andlinux.org/), these do not virtualize at all and run linux as a user mode application.
- You might want to install the Windows version of Player/Stage after all.

Comment: Thank you I will try some of those things. Just to add a note that as far as I know Player/Stage can run on Windows only in theory :)

Answer (score 0):

I see this has been answered already. I had an issue where 12.04 would run *unacceptably* slow in vbox and the issue was that IO-APIC was not activated. I wanted to post this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-an-ubuntu-12-10-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly) since it hasn't been mentioned but that thread is closed/protected.

Since it hasn't been mentioned here either, well, there you go: make sure you **activate IO-APIC**