# Windows only refresh if click on title bar (12.04-VirtualBox)

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a VirtualBox running on Windows 7 Pro. I have followed the instruction posted in [Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-an-ubuntu-12-10-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly)

Unity 3D seems to be loading OK but all windows only update their content when I click on the window title bar. Even terminal, in terminal I can press return a few times and nothing updates until I click on the title bar, then I can see the expect responses.

My system - 
VirtualBox (4.2.10 r84104) 
Extension Pack 4.2.10 
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 
Additions installed

I have

1. Install VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.
2. Create a VirtualBox instance and install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it.
3. apt-get update
4. apt-get upgrade
5. apt-get install dkms
6. Rebooted
7. cd /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.10_84104
8. sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
9. Rebooted
10. Add the vboxvideo driver to the instance by running:

    sudo bash -c 'echo vboxvideo >> /etc/modules'
11. Shutdown
12. In my BIOS enabled "Intel Virtualization Technology"
13. In Virtualbox set video memory 128MB and enable 3d acceleration
14. Boot Ubuntu guest, and check that 3D acceleration is working by running:

    /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

which returned

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
NOT blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes 
GL vertex program:        yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I have also installed and run CompizConfig Settings Manager but I can't find any framebuffer options. I think I just need to set some option somewhere but I have no idea where to look now.

P.S. Unity 2D works OK, but I would like to get Unity 3D working then I could try 12.10.

Comment: This may be a Windows graphics driver issue. However it may be worth  to try to increase the CPU cores used by the VM. You may need to set an execution cap below 100% if you assign all cores to the VM to have some CPU power left for the host.

Comment: Increase the CPU cores from 1 to 4 didn't help. I don't think it is a resources issue. It feels more like a configuration problem. I don't think it is even trying to update the screen until I click on the window title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like known issue of the VirtualBox running on hosts with NVidia adapters (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2985)

There are 2 ways to resolve:

1) update host's video drivers

2) if it doesn't help, turn off "3D acceleration" in your virtual machine settings

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to [Rom098's](https://askubuntu.com/users/184000/rom098) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/430326/792004), I had to activate "3D acceleration" in my virtual machine settings in order to make it work.