# Unity crashes when running Ubuntu in a VM

Tags: unity, virtualbox, compiz, virtualization

I can't get Ubuntu (tried both 12.10 and 13.10) to play nice with my VM. Everything looks fine when I log in, but trying to use the dashboard will cause a crash. The crash can be triggered by just about anything but the surest way to reproduce is to attempt to search for anything using the dashboard (top left Unity button).

When this happens, I am presented with a blank desktop:

[image]

#### What I've tried:

- I did this once while watching `~/.xsession-errors` with `tail -f` and nothing new appeared when the crash occurred.
- Deleting `~/.xsession-errors`, rebooting and triggering the crash again, does not recreate the file.
- I have installed guest additions on the guest OS

#### Details:

- Host OS: LMDE, basically Debian testing
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
- Virtual Machine: 4.3.8 r92456
- VM settings:

[image]
[image]
NOTE: Don't let the name fool you, I am actually running 13.10, the VM name is just left over from a previous install.

Comment: One cause of the crashes may be the 3D acceleration. What happens if you turn it off?

Comment: @Jos yes, I was just trying that but no dice, same crashes.

Comment: Have you tried turning 2D on? (sounds crazy I know...)

Comment: @EliahKagan not a dupe. Unity _does_ load, it crashes later.

Comment: @Seth I get this message if I try to check the 2d Acceleration tickbox: `The virtual machine is set up to use Virtual Stream Acceleration. As this feature only works with Windows guest operating systems, it will be disabled.`

Comment: @terdon Ah, yes. I remember that when I tried to enable 2D stuff.. nvm then I guess.

Comment: Nothing in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks, yes I do know those :). I am not sure whether it is a bug or not, I have tried two different Ubuntu versions and get the same crash (after attempting to use the dashboard) on both. That seems very strange for a bug and I was hoping I could install/configure something to get around it. And yes, it is a crash, fairly sure it is `compiz` (I got some messages to that effect but can't reproduce (the messages, the crash is still happening) now).

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, a core dump is a good idea, thanks, I'll do that if I end up submitting a bug report. And yes, crashes are often bugs but bugs often have solutions or workarounds which is why I posted here. If this boils down to "sorry, it's a bug" then I'll delete. However, since many people apparently successfully install Ubuntu in a VM I was hoping I was just doing something wrong.

Comment: @Braiam nothing relevant, no. The only errors are about mouse pointer integration and nothing new is written when the crash occurs.

Comment: @EliahKagan could you please either retract your close vote since this is not a dupe of the linked Q or vote to close as off topic if you think that is the case?

Comment: @EliahKagan you make a good point and thanks for explaining. Turns out it was not a bug but it is a dupe! Following the solution suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/214968/85695) fixed it. So please, let's close it as a dupe of that one instead.