# Strange screen fragment when using emacs

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, emacs

I am being bothered by the strange screen fragment while using `emacs`.

Sometimes, when I edit something in emacs, the screen gets fragmented like this:

> The lines are not correctly updated

[image]

Below is the correct display

[image]

---

My ubuntu is in **VirtualBox**. `The VirtualBox version is 4.3.10.` I have installed the `guest addition`.

The ubuntu I am using is

> ubuntu 13.10
>   Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
>   Chromium 64-bit

The emacs I am using should be the newest one

> GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.6) of
>   2014-01-03 on gold, modified by Debian

Comment: Try adding this to your `~/.emacs` file: ` (setq-default column-number-mode t)`. Does that help?

Comment: @terdon just did, let me use for a while and see whether it works. can you tell me what's the purpose of that setting?

Comment: Not really, no :) That's why this was just a comment. I had a similar, though not identical, problem and that helped. It is something to do with the number of columns your window has and seems to help with the drawing issues you describe. I believe the root of the problem is a miscommunication between emacs and the compositing window manager but I'm not sure.

Comment: @terdon sorry to tell ya that it didn't work. still I am having this issue

Comment: Yeah, that was just a wild shot in the dark. It _improved_ but did not fix it for me too. Are you using unity or another desktop environment?

Comment: @terdon I am using a virtual box hosting ubuntu 13.10, what do you mean by `unity` or `desktop environment`? sorry to ask this silly question as I am not actually a linux pro.

Comment: No worries, the desktop environment is the graphical interface you see, there are many but the dafault Ubuntu one is called `unity`. PLease [edit] your question and clarify that this is in a VM.  If you are using virtualbox, make sure you have installed the guest additions, they solve all sorts of graphics issues. Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/214968/85695) answer.

Comment: @terdon ok, but I installed guest additions, as if I didn't, I even couldn't use copy/paste lol

Comment: Yes, you also need to activate the unity plugin in compiz-config-settings-manager.

Comment: If you use `C-l` does it fix the garbled display?

Comment: Why don't you ask the guys on emacs-devel? If it is a display bug then they will be interested. http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel