# Can not enable 3D acceleration on Ubuntu 14.04 inside VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, hardware-acceleration

I'm running VirtualBox 4.3.12 on MacBook Pro 15.4" with OSX 10.9.3. Inside VirtualBox I have Ubuntu 14.04 (upgraded from 13.10).

I'm almost sure, that 3D Acceleration stopped working after VirtualBox upgrade from 4.3.10 version, but it also may be upgrade to 14.04 (or one of the following packages upgrade).

I've following directions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/214968/189752) several times, but no luck. Output still says that 3D Acceleration is not enabled:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

I found bug [#12941](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941) in VirtualBox Bug Tracker, but seems it isn't my case since I don't have any openGL errors.

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: just in case: did you re-install the guest additions after the release upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I did it several times.

Comment: I would recommend to fill a new bug report with upstream.

Comment: Well, closing this question is NOT that helpful. According to https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/3d_acceleration_with_ubuntu_guests there seems to be a race condition in kernel module loading (unsure if this is a Ubuntu bug). Try the following: sudo bash -c 'echo vboxvideo >> /etc/modules'

Comment: @aanno, accepted answer works for me, so I have closed this question. Blog post is published about a year ago, also your suggestion is a part of the directions, which I linked in my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the exact same issue except that I run VirtualBox 4.3.12r93733 on a Windows 7 host, not OSX.

After trying many different things without success, I had a look at the [linked VirtualBox bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941) which claimed "fixed as of 27 May 2014 in VirtualBox 4.3.x and later releases".

The very [last comment (as of today)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12941#comment:58) has a [link to a recent CD image for the VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-94159.iso).

After installing this in my 14.04 guest, the command line

`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

finally reports

`Unity 3D supported:       yes`

and all the Unity window animations are smooth as butter.

### Update 2014-07-20:

According to the latest comments on this answer, there is no need for downloading the CD image any more, as it has finally become part of the [official VirtualBox distribution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html). So if you upgrade, you'll get the fixed Guest Additions.

If you're stuck with a VirtualBox version without the fixed Guest Additions, you can get the CD images from the [VirtualBox download repository](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) - just find the correct version's folder and get the VBoxGuestAdditions_*.iso file inside it.

Comment: Fixed it for me. Apparently the ISO file is periodically updated. This is the current one, although it'll probably only be good for a short time: https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-94438.iso

Comment: @bmaupin: Thanks for the update. I am wondering when these guest additions with the fix will be finally included in the main VirtualBox download. Seems like they're still "test cases"... I therefore also find it a little funny that they claim "fixed as of 27 May 2014". Ah well, at least we have a workaround.

Comment: Both links are dead already. Look for the newest ISO here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ (currently 4.3.14). Fixed 3D in virtualbox for me :)

Comment: @wwwhizz Thanks for the update. Is that the official download repository? Are the Guest Additions still not part of the main download? And did you just find the latest folder in that directory and download the image from there?

Comment: @FriendFX Yes, that is the official download repository, and yes that's indeed what I did. I've just checked, and the ISO is included in the official host-application as well, so updating VirtualBox on your host machine would do the trick as well: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Comment: @wwwhizz That's great news, this will make my answer eventually obsolete, I am going to update it accordingly. +1 for checking.

Comment: is this answer still relevant? I just pulled 4.3.18 for my windows 8 host. I went into my ubuntu 64 bit VM, and re-installed the VBoxLinuxAdditions which did upgrade it to the version that came with 4.3.18, and my ubuntu desktop is still dreadfully slow.

Comment: @Derek, I am running the same version (VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.18_96516) under my Win7 host. It doesn't seem "dreadful" to me, but the `unity_support_test` command-line again reported **no** for "Unity 3D supported". Unfortunately I currently don't have time to investigate - I'd look if the latest GuestAdditions ISO from the VBox site is the same version and if not, try that instead.

Comment: I see. Maybe I will try that. I have "yes" for all the `unity_support_test` checks, but I see some anomalies (windows not rendering exactly right, and anything coming out of dash is painfully slow). I've turned off all fading and animation and stuff, but apparently that's not applicable to dash

Comment: @Derek, I also had some (very minor) rendering issues when `unity_support_test` was all `yes`. (Now that isn't the case on my VBox any more, these issues are gone.) Seems like you already have the maximum possible acceleration. As far as I remember, the dash has *always been* rather slow - even on my native Ubuntu 14.04 installation with acceleration. I wonder if there could be reasons other than graphics though...

Comment: I downloaded and installed the latest version for the major version I am using. It worked. http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.38/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.38.iso

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't enabled 3D acceleration with VirtualBox settings themselves, use this.

Go to the settings of the VirtualBox that Ubuntu is running in, click Video, and click enable 3d acceleration.

Comment: This tickbox is enabled.