# Is it possible to get a usable Ubuntu 15.04 running in Virtual Box on OS X?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, opengl

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.04 with the guest additions (on VirtualBox 5.0.2, video mem=128MB, 3d enabled). Graphics are very "sluggish" even with HiDPI (Retina) disabled.

After disabling all animations I could find I still can't use the Dash. It takes ~3 seconds to fade in and another ~3 to go away again.

I've also replaced the guest additions with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11` (no change).

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477738/can-not-enable-3d-acceleration-on-ubuntu-14-04-inside-virtualbox) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328459/how-to-enable-unity-3d-support-in-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-virtual-box-with-host-wind) answer did not help.

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.5.2

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no

$ modprobe -c|grep vboxvideo
alias pci:v000080EEd0000BEEFsv*sd*bc*sc*i* vboxvideo
```

I also get a message about "vboxvideo: module verification failed":

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog|grep vbox
Aug 30 23:14:09 udev vboxadd[8667]: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...done.
Aug 30 23:14:10 udev vboxadd-service[8754]: Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service  ...done.
Aug 30 23:14:10 udev systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 30 23:14:10 udev systemd[1]: Unit vboxadd-service.service entered failed state.
Aug 30 23:14:10 udev systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service failed.
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev kernel: [14302.735185] vboxvideo: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev kernel: [14302.736192] [drm] Initialized vboxvideo 1.0.0 20090303 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev kernel: [14302.942282] vboxguest: misc device minor 56, IRQ 20, I/O port d020, MMIO at 00000000f0400000 (size 0x400000)
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev kernel: [14302.942283] vboxguest: Successfully loaded version 5.0.2 (interface 0x00010004)
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev kernel: [14306.524633] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.0.2 (interface 0x00010004)
Aug 30 23:14:42 udev systemd-modules-load[188]: Inserted module 'vboxvideo'
Aug 30 23:14:43 udev vboxadd[634]: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...done.
Aug 30 23:14:43 udev vboxadd-service[896]: Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service  ...done.
Aug 30 23:14:43 udev systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 30 23:14:43 udev systemd[1]: Unit vboxadd-service.service entered failed state.
Aug 30 23:14:43 udev systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service failed.
```

I'd guess this is a bug ([I reported it here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14522)) but is there a workaround? Can I force vboxvideo to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to VirtualBox 5.0.4 fixed the issue:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
[...]
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

It still can't load vboxvideo but 3D is working and Unity is now usable.