# 14.04 running slow in VirtualBox. Enabling 3D Acceleration caused OS to crash on login

Tags: unity, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox on my computer at work, with Windows as the host OS and Ubuntu as the Guest. Ubuntu, inside of VB, is EXTREMELY slow. A quick google showed me this was a common problem with a somewhat easy fix: [Install guest additions and enable 3D acceleration](https://askubuntu.com/a/214968/269026). I had already installed guest additions previously, but I went ahead and ran through the process again just to make sure everything was up-to-date. I then shut down my VB instance and enabled 3D Acceleration in the settings.

After doing that, however, I hit my big problem. I started up my instance of Ubuntu, but as soon as I logged in the instance crashed. This happens upon login every time.

I went back and unchecked the box for 3D Acceleration, and the instance began working again (at the same slow pace as before).

Any ideas what could be causing the crash? Could I not have enough RAM reserved for the VB? Would that cause this issue?

---

I'm also open to suggestions for a different VB that won't have this problem.

Comment: Is the Host VBOX at the latest version?

Comment: 4.3.10 r93012. Yep.

4.3.12 is actually out now, but when I try to update it says "The network operation failed with the following error: Unknown reason"