# Ubuntu on VirtualBox very very slow (revisited)

Tags: virtualbox, 15.04, guest-os

Using Virtualbox 5.0 with Windows 8.1 as host and Ubuntu 14.04.2 as guest.
It is extremely slow. I have tried

1) Increasing the RAM size

2) Used multiple processors in Systems->Processor tab (have IntelCore i7 processor)

3) Enabled 3D Acceleration in Display->Screen tab

4) Increased the video memory

5) Tried enabling/disabling Extended features in the settings

6) Also tried Ubuntu-15.04 (behavior remains the same)

Here's ([Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly?rq=1)) from a user some time back.

The system is still slow...is there anything to be done in the BIOS? and i doubt it, as my windows is pretty fast. Any help appreciated! (Thanks!)

Comment: Have you tried to install VirtualBox Guest Additions ?

Comment: Did you install guest additions?

Comment: Have you tried changing the virtual machine's chipset?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and suggestions ( I will work on them in a shortwhile). i am trying to re-install now the Ubuntu guest, and its been an hour and its still going on.

Comment: Did you enabled VT-X hardware acceleration on your BIOS and VM config?,  also maybe you're using a x86 guest ubuntu instead of x64.

Comment: 1) Changed the Chipset to ICH9

2) Installed Guest Additions (It is latest now)

3) My V-Box version is  5.0.0-101573-Win (It is 64 bit)


It is still slow. I am going to try with the "VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC3-101436-Win.exe" version. Thanks again!

Comment: @bistoco: Your options were already enabled (double verified)

Comment: Here's some more things you can try to speed up your virtual Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

> Alright, so it was kind of my bad. After installation I did my first
>   `sudo apt-get update` and realized my **network connection wasn't**
>   **working correctly**. It was due to the way I set up my VM where I set the network
>   adapter to attach to bridged network. This must've had caused the installation
>   process to choke up like that. When retrying installation I left the
>   VM settings to standard and every was smoof. Hope this is helpful to
>   someone out there.

I feel your pain. If indeed the issues you're referring are:

- During the beginning of installation everything seems to run fine
- further in the installation things starts to look like frozen
- wait long enough (15+ min) to see progress
- occuring multiple times during installation

To be honest, I have tried to figure it out. **No it's not the 3D hardware acceleration**. It seems to me like it is the **Paravirtualization Interface** which I have set both to KVM and Hyper-V for testing but in both cases the issues persists. I stopped trying other settings once I got my Ubuntu 14.04 Server setup because I couldn't risk another hour of waiting for the installation to complete, it's ridiculous.

So my best guess is try either setting your **System > Acceleration > Paravirtualization** to anything other than I mentioned above, or **System > Motherboard > Chipset** selection somewhere?