# Ubuntu in VirtualBox very slow even with Guest Additions installed

Tags: virtualbox

I tried to follow the instructions here: [Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly)

However, I cannot get `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to work as it says `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` not found, even though I already tried `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils` and restarted. And when I type `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`, it still says Utiliy 3D is not supported and a bunch of lines with `OpenGL warning: [..] not found in mesa table`. What is going on?

Comment: So be able to install the guest addition we need to mount the CD/ISO first, then `cd` to the (mounted) disk image to then run the installer script as root. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: I followed the instructions there, and I think Guest Additions was installed successfully so I rebooted,however I'm having problems at `Note 2`. Even though I `cd /usr/share/virtualbox/` and when I `ls` I see the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`, when I `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, it keeps saying `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run command not found`

Comment: You have to **mount** that ISO in the virtual machine. Only then you will be able to run the guest additions installer script from the guest Ubuntu.

Comment: ok, I was able to run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and after rebooting, VirtualBox is now much faster than before, although it is still too slow and barely tolerable. I then typed `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`, but I still see `Unity 3d supported: no`. why is this?! I see under `settings` ->`display` that `3d acceleration` is still clicked